# Is there a faster way to check if the sign of the data entry is different than the sign of the data entry in previous row for a given pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, row

I am trying to find how many times the data entries in column 'Delta' has changed signs (from positive to negative or vice versa) within fixed number of rows

Here is the small sample of the dataframe that I am working on and the method that I have tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0,1,2,3,4,5], 'Delta':[1,2,-3,4,5,-7]})

j=1
step=4    
for i in range(1,df.shape[0]):
    if j<df.shape[0]-3:
        for j in range(j,j+3):
            df['Spike'].iloc[j]=(df['Delta'].iloc[i]>0)-(df['Delta'].iloc[i-1]>0)
    j=j+step
```

The purpose of `for j` loop is perform this 'change of sign check' on given fixed number of rows.

The desired output would be **3**, since the values in the 'Delta' columns has changed the sign 3 times

Unfortunately, this code takes a lot of time. My guess is that pandas checks each row one by one making the whole code run slower. Since I want to implement the code on a much bigger data ( millions of rows) I would appreciate if someone would advise a faster solution

Comment: Question not clear . Delta column has all positive continuous values, so, no change in sign. Or have I misread something? Can you also post the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect whether a row has changed sign from the previous row, you can multiply them and check whether the result is less than zero. You can use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to align an entry with the row above it in order to compare them in a single Series operation:

```
df['Delta'] * df['Delta'].shift() < 0
```

This will return a new Series with True's every time sign has changed.

Now in order to find how many times sign has changed in a window of 4 rows, you can use [`Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) on this derived series, and then simply `sum()` the entries together (in a `sum()`, True will be 1 and False will be 0, so the result of `sum()` will be the number of True's in the window.)

```
df['Spike'] = (df['Delta'] * df['Delta'].shift() < 0).rolling(4).sum()
```

This seems to be close to what you're doing now, perhaps slightly different in that this code is looking at past entries while your code is looking at future entries (perhaps another use of `shift(3)` or so would fix that if you need it?)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
>>> s = df.groupby(df['Delta'].lt(0).ne(df['Delta'].lt(0).shift())).size()
>>> s[s.index == False].item()
2
>>>
```